# How app Owner can update new data in existing database in iphone?(More Description is below)

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How app owner can update new data in existing database of app without any webservices...?
example like if there store 10 record in an app and after than another 5 record , app owner want to add in existing database than how to do it,is developer have to add this new data manually,,?? or  is there any other way ? is there like Backend in iphone ?

Comment: sorry my english is poor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your database then you have to submit new version of your app with changes in your database.

IF you don't want to submit new version then follow webService.
Web Service is best practice to do this task.

Web service is also an external dataBase, so you can change it as per your requirement.